# Syntax error near "posedge"

Tags: verilog

i'm trying to make the change the state at every posedge of clk and posedge of sclk and the compiler is throwing error at posedge.

```
module spi(output mosi,
                input miso,
                input dbus,
                input sclk,input cs,
                input clk,
                input rst_b);


reg [1:0] state;
reg [1:0] next_state;





else if (posedge clk && posedge sclk) begin
state <= next_state;
                    if(clr == 0) 
                        count <= 0; 
                    else if(inc == 1) 
                        count <= count +1;
```

Comment: Flip-flops only have one clock input, what hardware are you trying to generate?

Comment: i'm doing spi interfacing, cpol and cpha. so i used 2 clocks one is system clock that is fgpa's and the master clock-sclk

Comment: ok, `(posedge clk && posedge sclk)` does not mean anything, You really need to run off a single clock and add synchronisation for signals crossing between clock domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong with this.  Firstly, why are you using two clocks "clk" and "sclk" and ANDing them together?  Just use one.  Secondly, this all should be inside an `always` block.  Don't use posedge with an `if` statement.

E.g.

```
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
  // do stuff
```

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new to verilog: actually i'm not adding them i'm doing the stuff when both the clocks are at their posedge at an instant.

Comment: No problem!  I hope learning it is going well!  Like others have been saying, if you have two clocks, you need to be very careful about how they interact.  They can cause problems when trying to send data between them.  Read more about crossing clock domains if this is really something that you need to do.  A better solution is to figure out how you can do everything you need to do with just ONE clock.